# Stop script if onclick validation fails

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript validation script named validate().

I have another javascript function with generates a form named process().

I have a button:

```
<input name='Submit' type='submit' value='button' onclick='return validate()'>
```

This button is defined in a form named arg_form which in turn is defined in function process(). The form is:

```
 "<form name='arg_form' method='POST' action='x.php'>
```

Now, when I click on the button, the validation is done.
The problem here is, regardless of the validation, the file x.php runs.
What I want is, I want the x.php file to run only if the validate() function works.

Please help me, I am stuck here since the last 3 hours.

EDIT: What the validation script does is that it creates alert if some condition is not satisfied and returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <form name='arg_form' method='POST' action='x.php' onsubmit='return validate()'>
```

It will stop the form submission if the method returns false.